# Проверка на существование записи перед вставкой

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, insert

Здравствуйте! 
Как элегантно выполнить поиск записи в таблице, а при её отсутствие вставить и вернуть id?

Таблица

```
CREATE TABLE public."FORMAT"
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  short_name character(1) NOT NULL,
  name character varying(15),
  CONSTRAINT "FORMAT_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Делал так, но можно это иначе?

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.insert_or_select_param_name(
    _name character varying,
    _short_name character varying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ 
    DECLARE 
  id_param_name integer;
 BEGIN 

 --Есть ли такая запись?
  if(_name is null) 
then
id_param_name=(select id from "FORMAT" WHERE "FORMAT".short_name = _short_name AND "FORMAT".name is null);
ELSE
id_param_name= (select id from "FORMAT" WHERE "FORMAT".short_name = _short_name AND "FORMAT".name=_name);
END IF;

if(id_param_name is null) then
insert into public."FORMAT"(name,short_name) values(_name,_short_name) returning id into id_param_name;
End if;

return id_param_name;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
insert into public."PARAMETER_NAME"(name,short_name)
 select _name, _short_name
  where not exists(select 1 from public."PARAMETER_NAME"
                    where short_name = _short_name
                      and coalesce(name,'')=coalesce(_name,'')
                  )
returning id into id_param_name;
```

Второй вариант: Сделать невозможной повтор записей сделав уникальный индекс. К сожалению в postgress записи с NULL в индексе не содержатся и уникальность для них не проверяется. Для решения этой проблемы надо сделать функциональный индекс:

```
create unique index public."PARAMETER_NAME_UNIQ"
    on public."PARAMETER_NAME"(_short_name, coalesce(name,''));
```

После чего ваш insert можно написать в таком виде:

```
BEGIN
  insert into public."PARAMETER_NAME"(name,short_name)
   values(_name,_short_name) returning id into id_param_name;
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
        -- Ничего не делаем, либо сообщаем об ошибке дублирования и т.п.
END;
```

Comment: Это же общая транзакция?

Comment: @DamirGafarov Да, единый SQL-запрос - транзакция одна. Я только не знаю, что сделает постгресс, когда запись есть и returning нечего возвращать, он переменную id_param_name не изменит или ошибку выдаст. Если второе - то ошибку придется перехватывать.

Comment: Тогда после перехвата исключения, что бы вернуть id уже существующей записи нужно select выполнить? А тогда состояние гонки возникнуть не может?

Comment: @DamirGafarov Я сразу не понял, что вам обязательно надо получить ID ... Тогда второй вариант не плох. Проблема может возникнуть если вы пытаетесь вставить запись, она есть, вы начинаете в блоке exception получать ее id но в этот момент запись кто то удаляет и вы ее не находите. По идее в таком случае можно попробовать повторить вставку :)

Comment: Чем обосновано использование уникальных индексов? Тем что у обычного ограничения уникальности нельзя написать: ALTER TABLE "PARAMETER_NAME"
ADD CONSTRAINT PARAMETER_NAME_unique Unique (short_name, coalesce(name,''));

Comment: @DamirGafarov Тем, что не во всех СУБД есть такой синтаксис добавления констраинтов и мне не привычен :) И в любом случае они обеспечиваются за счет индекса и он все равно будет построен.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47108/discussion-between-damir-gafarov-and-mike).